# Unable to load kernel module after compiling it separately

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, device-driver

I am trying to "make" and load the "/drivers/md/raid0.ko" module into my linux kernel but I am getting this error.

```
# modprobe raid0 --force-vermagic
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'raid0': Exec format error
```

dmesg

```
[Dec 2 15:10] raid0: version magic '5.0.0 SMP mod_unload ' should be '5.0.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload '
```

My kernel version is

```
# uname -a
Linux ubuntu1 5.0.0-36-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 09:46:06 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and the code from which I am trying to load is taken from the link https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.0.tar.xz

Hence the version in that is 5.0.0, without the EXTRAVERSION -36

I have tried a number of things but failed.

1. Setting the EXTRAVERSION using command `make EXTRAVERSION=-1 modules_prepare`, before building the module
2. Using the `--force-vermagic` while loading the kernel, but it fails.
3. Copying the Makefile firectly from `/usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/Makefile` before building the kernel.

I have used both `make SUBDIRS=drivers/md modules` and `make M=drivers/md` for building, but same result for both.

Need help!

Comment: You have to use the headers from the running kernel (either kernel-headers / linux-headers package or, if it needs some internals, kernel-sources / linux-sources one. Whichever suits to the distro you are using.

Comment: For Ubuntu:   https://askubuntu.com/questions/159833/how-do-i-get-the-kernel-source-code (actually this topic is good for Ubuntu part of StackExchange)

Comment: @0andriy, well I am using the steps in https://askubuntu.com/questions/515407/how-recipe-to-build-only-one-kernel-module

but facing some other issue.. so thought may be there is a generic way of doing this.

Comment: @Haris: "Generic way" is to build the module against the build tree **corresponded** to your target kernel. That is, if you want to run the module in the `5.0.0-36-generic` kernel (provided in Ubuntu), then you need to use build tree `/usr/lib/modules/5.0.0-36-generic/build` (provided by the appropriate Ubuntu package). If you have faced the problem when following that approach, then describe that problem.

Comment: @Tsyvarev. I was trying that, but it was not working at first. Right now I have made it work by changing the `EXTRAVERSION` change in the main Makefile.

Answer (score -1):

force modprobe to ignore the magic str

use **--force-vermagic** optin

> Every module contains a small string containing important information,
> such as the kernel and compiler versions. If a module fails to load
> and the kernel complains that the "version magic" doesn't match, you
> can use this option to remove it. Naturally, this check is there for
> your protection, so this using option is dangerous. This applies to
> any modules inserted: both the module (or alias) on the command line
> and any modules on which it

in this case modprob ignore magic str